# How to position 90° rotated text in the middle of parent element

Tags: css

I want the text transformed vertically to be in the middle of containing element
(so far it is displayed at top of the parent div).
My code can be seen here:

CSS:

```
  .row{ 
   float:right;
   clear:right;
   width:830px;

 }
.caption{
   width:50px;
   background:dimGray;
   height:300px;
   margin:3px 3px 0 0;
   float:left;
   line-height: 50px;
   position: relative;

}
.diagramm{
   height:300px;
   float:left;
   background:lightGrey;
    width:770px;
    margin:3px 0 0 0;

 }
.rotate
{
     white-space: nowrap;
     -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
     -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
     transition:  rotate(90deg);
                 filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=3); /* IE6, IE7 */
     -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=3)" /* IE8 */;


                 -webkit-transform-origin:50% 50%;

     color:white;
     font-weight:bold;

 }
```

========================
HTML:

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="caption">
     <div class="rotate">
    text
                  </div>
   </div>
    <div class="diagramm">
            <div id="chart_" style="height:300px; width:500px;">
    </div>
   </div> 
</div>
</body>
```

http://jsbin.com/unogov/3/edit

Comment: Post your code here, please. And explain how what you've done already has failed to meet your objectives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe there is a more elegant way to do it, but it works...
Just add these lines into the `.rotate`

```
top: 125px;
left: -125px;
text-align: center;
position: relative;
width: 300px;
```